# Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multiclass and continuous-multioutput targets

Tags: tensorflow, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding, multiclass-classification

I am running a `BERT` pretrained model on a  `multiclass` dataset for text classification purposes. Since it is multiclass I cannot figure out how to generate a `classification report`. The solutions I found were [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48987959/classification-metrics-cant-handle-a-mix-of-continuous-multioutput-and-multi-la) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56492186/f-score-valueerror-classification-metrics-cant-handle-a-mix-of-multilabel-ind). I understand since its a multiclass classification I have to `one-hot-encode` the `test_y` values (which I did)

```
test_y = to_categorical(np.asarray(test_y.factorize()[0]))
```

but when I do

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
print(classification_report(test_y, y_pred, digits=8))
```

I get still get this error :

```
     88     if len(y_type) > 1:
     89         raise ValueError("Classification metrics can't handle a mix of {0} "
---> 90                          "and {1} targets".format(type_true, type_pred))
     91 
     92     # We can't have more than one value on y_type => The set is no more needed

ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multilabel-indicator and continuous-multioutput targets
```

Why?

And if I try to calculate `accuracy_score` I get `0.0` accuracy: (but my accuracy is around 60%)

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
y_pred = np.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)
accuracy_score(test_y, y_pred)
>> 0.0
```

Why?

Details of the model is given below:

> train_test_split

```
train, test, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(df['text'], df['label'],test_size = 0.3)
```

> Model:

```
 def build_model(bert_layer, max_len=512):
    input_word_ids = Input(shape=(max_len,), dtype=tf.int32, name="input_word_ids")
    input_mask = Input(shape=(max_len,), dtype=tf.int32, name="input_mask")
    segment_ids = Input(shape=(max_len,), dtype=tf.int32, name="segment_ids")

    _, sequence_output = bert_layer([input_word_ids, input_mask, segment_ids])
    clf_output = sequence_output[:, 0, :]
    #out = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(clf_output)
    out = Dense(8, activation='sigmoid')(clf_output)
    
    model = Model(inputs=[input_word_ids, input_mask, segment_ids], outputs=out)
    model.compile(Adam(lr=2e-6), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    
    return model
```

> Model.fit

```
    train_history = model.fit(train_input, train_labels, validation_split=0.2, epochs=1,batch_size=16 )
```

> model.predict

```
y_pred = model.predict(test_input)
```

> Shape of parameters

```
print(type(y_pred))
print(y_pred.shape)
>> <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
>> (621,)

print(type(test_y)) #before running to_categorical
print(test_y.shape)
>> <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
>>(621,)
```

Comment: Just print out `test_y` and `y_pred` and check of they both are in same format

Answer (score 1):

Well, your output layer is defined as  `out = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(clf_output)`, which means there is a single output node followed by sigmoid activation. This is meant to train on a objective of Binary classification or regression where the output values is a real number ranging between 0 and 1. To change it to binary labels using a threshold. This can be done using

```
threshold =0.5 # this can be changed. For simplistic example, let uss consider 0.5
y_pred = np.where(y<threshold,0,1)
```

Or, if it is multiclass problem, then change `out = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(clf_output)` to `out = Dense(number_of_classes, activation='sigmoid')(clf_output)`

Comment: i did it gives the same result

Comment: You may have to adjust your threshold. Vary between 0.1 to 0.9 in steps on 0.1 and look for change.